# Using require_once with sessions in PHP / verification system with sessions

Tags: php, session, require

I'm trying to do a Todo website, I am at the end of programming it but I got into some problems.

When trying to use require_once with sessions it won't work, I'm trying to make a verification with the second part of code, as soon as the password is right and submitted the session value "login" should be set to true, but It doesn't do it, and just sends me to the error file that is set in the second part of the code.
Thanks for your inputs and help.

Here is my code:

Code that should set my $_SESSION["login"] to "true" (`$_SESSION['login'] = true;`)

```
<?php
require_once "B_session.php";
require_once "DB_connection.php";

$mysqli = connection();
$error = '';
$message = '';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && empty($error)){

    if(!empty(trim($_POST['username']))){
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        if(!preg_match("/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]{4,}/", $username) || strlen($username) > 30){
            $error .= "Der Benutzername entspricht nicht dem geforderten Format.<br />";}
    } else {
        $error .= "Geben Sie bitte den Benutzername an.<br />";
    }

    if(!empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        if(!preg_match("/(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/", $password)){
            $error .= "Das Passwort entspricht nicht dem geforderten Format.<br />";
        }
    } else {
        $error .= "Geben Sie bitte das Passwort an.<br />";
    }


    if(empty($error)){
        $query = "SELECT username, password, rights from users where username = ?";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();

        if(!$stmt->bind_param("s", $username)){
            $error .= 'bind_param() failed '. $mysqli->error . '<br />';
        }

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            $error .= 'execute() failed '. $mysqli->error . '<br />';
        }

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if($result->num_rows){
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            if(password_verify($password, $row["password"]))
                $message .= "Sie sind nun eingeloggt";
                $_SESSION['login'] = true;    
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row["username"];
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $row["admin"];
                if ($row["admin"]) {
                    header('Location: ../Administrator/A_home.php');

                } else {
                    header('Location: Backend/U_home.php');
                }
        } else {
            $error .= "Benutzername oder Passwort sind falsch";
        }
    } else {
        $error .= "Benutzername oder Passwort sind falsch";
    }
}
```

code of the included file "B_session.php":

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == false) {
    header("location: ../Backend/B_error.html");
}
```

My login form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Registrierung</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="Backend/loginPost.php" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="login.php" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="adminlogin.php" class="active" id="register-form-link">register as admin</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <form id="login-form" action="Backend/loginPost.php" method="post" role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The B_session script is checking the session value is set before you have chance to check if the user credentials are validated.  For the login page, you don't do this check, just start the session.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not check where this goes wrong? Also, keep in mind that you should use `exit()` after sending a `Location` header

Comment: @NigelRen I see, so can I just implement this in my code instead of doing an require to prevent this?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tryied to add the values to a variable first, and to change require to include, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have just changed the values and put it all in the first part of the code I sent (another file), it doesn't fix it, same problem, I even made sure to define SESSION "login" to true and to check it after. @NigelRen

Comment: I just put the verification out, but it just makes nothing not even redirects me to another file